# how to sort lines *.txt after 3_line in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to sorted file according 1 column and after 3 line and before last line. For example:[image]

My code:

```
String line;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\file.txt");
StreamWriter fileSorted = new StreamWriter(@"c:\fileSorted.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    fileSorted.WriteLine(line);
}

file.Close();
fileSorted.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you've already done.  This is not a forum where others just write code for you.

Comment: you want to sort the second column but only the elements between the third and the last one?

Comment: So you want to group on the first column value maintaining the original order from the original file within each group?

Comment: yes, I want to gorup on first column without without first and second line.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd use `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` for reading and writing the data.  Then you just need to capture the first 2 lines, the last line, and sort the rest.  The sorting is actually grouping on the numerical value in the first column (I'm assuming there are spaces between columns, so you might need to change that if it's actually tabs).  Then just order the groups on the keys and flatten them back out with `SelectMany`.  Finally you just concat the header to the sorted lines and concat that to the trailer and write it to your file.

```
var input = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file.txt");

var header = input.Take(2);
var sorted = input.Skip(2).Take(input.Length - 3)
    .GroupBy(line => int.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(" "))))
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .SelectMany(g => g);
var trailer = input.Skip(input.Length - 1);

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\fileSorted.txt", header.Concat(sorted).Concat(trailer));
```

Comment: Your solution is good but now i don't need WriteAllLines to file, i must write AllLines to TAB []. I thing this is easy but i can't do this...

Now i have:

STRING [] TAB = Fille.ReadAllLines(@"c:\fileSorted.txt");
I would like it right away (without File.WriteAllLines )

STRING [] TAB = header.Concat(sorted).Concat(trailer);

Comment: I'd o what i want

            var ResualData = header.Concat(sorted).Concat(trailer);

            string[] tab = new string [dl];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in ResualData)
            {
                tab[i] = item;
                i ++;
            }
If you know faster method please write

Comment: @MariuszNazwiskoo I'd recommend writing a new question as the comment section is not a good place to answer questions.